# iOS How to search data at the few Data table Parse swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have search module, which connected to the parse.

And i want to make searching from few data table base.

For searching i use next code:

```
var searchResult = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchResult.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = searchResult[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

For searching bar this code:

```
 func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    let firstQuery = PFQuery(className: "fried")
    firstQuery.whereKey("best", contains: searchBar.text)

    let seccondQuery = PFQuery(className: "home")
    seccondQuery.whereKey("home", contains: searchBar.text)

    let query = PFQuery.orQuery(withSubqueries: [firstQuery,seccondQuery])
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (result, error) in
        if let objects = result {
            self.searchResult.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

            for object in objects {
                let question = object.object(forKey: "question") as! String
                let answer = object.object(forKey: "answer1") as! String
                let test = question + " " + answer

                self.searchResult.append(test)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.resignFirstResponder()
            }

        }
    }

}
```

And i got this type of error:

> reason: 'All sub queries of an `or` query should be on the same class.'

It's possible to make searching at the few data base?

Comment: Search one class at a time

Comment: @Carpsen90 but i have key word, and i want to search at 2 data base

Comment: Side note: `className: "fried"` maybe you've meant "friend"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search one class at a time, `orQuery` is done on subqueries of the same class

```
self.searchResult.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false) // Start by emptying the search resulys array

firstQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (result, error) in
    if let objects = result {
        for object in objects {
            let question = object.object(forKey: "question") as! String
            let answer = object.object(forKey: "answer1") as! String
            let test = question + " " + answer
            self.searchResult.append(test)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}

seccondQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (result, error) in
    if let objects = result {
        for object in objects {
            let question = object.object(forKey: "question") as! String
            let answer = object.object(forKey: "answer1") as! String
            let test = question + " " + answer
            self.searchResult.append(test)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Or more consizely:

```
let queryArry = [firstQuery, secondQuery]
for query in queryArray {
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (result, error) in
        if let objects = result {
            for object in objects {
                let question = object.object(forKey: "question") as! String
                let answer = object.object(forKey: "answer1") as! String
                let test = question + " " + answer
                self.searchResult.append(test)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: but i case if i will have 10 base, i need 10 time write this code?